# Get the exact input text of a function

Tags: r, string

I want to get the exact input text of a function argument and print it out in the output. For example, the following function will take a vector of integers and return their squares.

```
> my_func <- function(x) {
+     print(paste0("The square of ", toString(x), " is: ", toString(x^2)))
+ }
> my_func(1:4)
[1] "The square of 1, 2, 3, 4 is: 1, 4, 9, 16"
```

The output I want is

```
The square of "1:4" is: 1, 4, 9, 16
```

where `1:4` is exactly the input text to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my_func <- function(x) {
    print(paste0("The square of ", deparse(x), " is: ", toString(x^2)))
}
```

Comment: what's the `substitute` for? Seems to work with just `deparse` for me...

Comment: Without `substitute()` the argument given as `x` will be evaluated; and in that case you don't even need `deparse()`. You need both of them if you want to handle unevaluated expressions as input, e.g. `f(1 + 2)` or `f(a + b)`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I do tend to believe that the argument will be given in the most simplified format. on using `substitute` the following will fail: `y=c(1:5,6:10);f(y)` but with `deparse` alone, it will call y and sicnce the difference is 1, it will output it as 1:10

Comment: @Onyambu I see, that's interesting! Clearly `deparse()` is still useful on it's own, too, then. I guess whether or not you need substitute depends on how OP wants to handle e.g. `f(1:4 / 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using `eval` `parse` and passing input as string

```
my_func <- function(x) {
   cat("The square of ", x, " is: ", eval(parse(text = x))^2)
}

my_func("1:4")
#The square of  1:4  is:  1 4 9 16

my_func("3:6")
#The square of  3:6  is:  9 16 25 36
```